# Using JDO in Elastic Beanstalk results in ClassNotPersistenceCapableException

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdo, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I implemented an application with Elastic Beanstalk. Since some classes shall be persisted, I use (Apache's) JDO annotations in combination with DataNucleus.

When running the application on a local server everything works fine, meaning I can persist plain old Java objects to the connected Amazon RDS. When deploying the same application to Elastic Beanstalk I receive following error message:

```
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "edu.kit.aifb.cloudcampus.dom.mgmt.Dozent" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
NestedThrowables:
org.datanucleus.exceptions.ClassNotPersistableException: The class "edu.kit.aifb.cloudcampus.dom.mgmt.Dozent" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.

org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:380)
    org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
    org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:751)
```

I am wondering why this is happening, since I have programmaticaly enhanced my classes with following lines of code

```
public void enhanceJDOClasses(String...clazzes) {
    JDOHelper.getEnhancer().addClasses(clazzes).enhance();
}
```

Is there any recommended way to handle this in another way or did anybody experience similar exceptions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the enhanced version of the class is not in the current classLoader. That command doesn't put it there, just enhances the classes, and once a class (unenhanced) is loaded in a ClassLoader it can't be replaced. You can however set the classLoader to the enhancer

Comment: Ah, ok. So you mean 
`public void enhanceJDOClasses(String...clazzes) {
  ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  JDOHelper.getEnhancer(contextClassLoader).addClasses(clazzes).enhance();
 } `

will fix the problem? I'll give it a try. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: That did it. Now I have other exceptions flying around. But that solved the first problem. Thanks.